# Functions declared within a function in C, are they usable at a global scope?

Tags: c, function, scope

I've been running into a minor problem with regards to seeing people, currently helping a teacher out through grading, and seeing people declaring functions within the scope of main, instead of within the global scope, as I was taught to do, I understand that this still works in itself, but I am kind of confused as to what happens with these functions, should a function be called, that was declared in main, in another function that is not declared inside said main, would this in itself work, and if it does, why. Isn't the function within only the scope of main, and as such shouldn't it remain local to it, or dies C just allocate the space in memory for the functions call at a global scope from the time it is declared, and subsequently defined? Know I was rambling a bit on this, trying to cover all possible questions within this scope.
Sample of what I mean.

```
int main(){  
  void foo(int bar);
  int boo;
  foo(boo);
  return 0;
}

void foo(int bar){
  ...
}
```

The point that I was trying to stress is that the functions are usable due to the fact that they are related, through main if that makes any sense, but should a function be declared on the global scope such as

```
#include <stdio.h>

void roo(void);

int main(){} //Holds the same syntax as above with the function declared within it.
//Function foo is same as defined prior.
//Then function roo is defined but uses foo within itself.

void roo(void){
int boo;
foo(boo);
...
}
```

Shouldn't the codes being compounded, not work fully since the function roo technically has no way to access the function within the scope of main?

edit --

I somewhat saw a point that main would be, with the current lack of multiple functions to be called, would still be at the time used to call function roo, but should this contain multiple functions then wouldn't it be kind of weird or not syntax legal to call up foo from within roo, if it were scaled about 6 functions outside from main.

Comment: Defining a function within a function is legal in some compilers, but is not available in the language in general.  (eg, it is a gnu extension)

Comment: As long as there is a declaration of the function before you call it, you can call it. The code snippet you show is perfectly legal.

Comment: Your question and your code example appear to describe different things. Perhaps you could extend the example to show all of what you're envisaging?

Comment: Ok. That was the main point of my rather lon explanation, I was unsure of how to properly word it, but I can clean the code snippet up a bit, and to everyone elses response, thnak you. I was told that it was bad practice due to readability, did not know that it was compiler exclusive WilliamPursell JoachimPileborg, you guys are somewhat contradicting each other on that point though, aren't you?

Comment: They aren't - *declaring* a function and *defining* a function are separate things (although a definition is also a declaration). *Definition* means the function's body is written out. GCC lets you put that inside another function - which is unrelated to what you have here.

Comment: I understand that the definition can itself be used as the declaration, if that's what you're aiming to push forward with that, but I remember when I used to attempt to compile functions before, without explicitly declaring them, I see that the functions are being defined, I just felt that they needed to be defined within the global scope, and that for some weird reason I felt that they would not link through the points in main. I feel as if I'm not being too concise with my explanation, mainly because I feel that I am in a way confusing myself, with my own explanation, sorry if I do the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declarations are needed for type checking and linking. They exist at compile-time only - they don't actually create an "object" (such as a function body) that exists in any way in the compiled program - all they do is put a name on it, so that other parts of the source can *refer to* that object without having it immediately to hand. *Definitions* create objects, but *declarations* create names.

Going through your example:

```
void roo(void);  // roo becomes visible

int main(){  // main is defined, AND becomes visible
    void foo(int bar);  // foo becomes visible
    foo(6);
    roo();
}  // foo is no longer visible

void foo(int bar){ /**/ }  // foo is defined AND becomes visible

void roo(void){  // roo is defined, but was already visible
    foo(6);      //  so this has no effect on other functions
}
```

1. `roo` can be called from any code in the program below where it was declared, because its name has been put in global scope and is visible from all nested scopes. The following code is *aware* that *somewhere* (no idea where), a function called `roo` exists and is available for use.
2. Moving down into `main`, a new scope is opened, and `foo` made visible within it. `main` uses this information to call to `foo`. It uses the information in the global scope to call to `roo`. The scope closes with the end of `main` and `foo` ceases to be visible to the following code; it is not aware that any such function exists.
3. `foo` is the simultaneously defined and declared in the global scope. All following code is aware that a function called `foo` is available for use.
4. Similarly for `roo`.

The only places anything is given space in memory are at the three points of *definition*. None of the declarations cause anything to be allocated, statically or otherwise. All they do is make the code *aware* of an allocation elsewhere (to be resolved by the linker).

So to (what I think was) the original point of confusion: `main` calls `roo`, and `roo` calls `foo`, but the declaration of `foo` in `main` is not visible to `roo`. (It sounds like you're confusing static and dynamic semantics: C has static scope only.)

This isn't a problem, because `main` doesn't know the content of `roo`, and doesn't need to know its content (some compilers perform inlining; we don't care about that). Control *leaves* the body code of `main` and goes to a different point in the program. The body of a function is a black box to every other function; what happens within the code of `roo` is completely unknown to every other function. `roo` also doesn't inherit the scope of `main`, so it has *no* knowledge of anything that was declared at that time (globally, locally, or otherwise) - it uses the scope opened and closed by its own body further down for name lookups. In that scope, `foo` has already been declared globally (it inherits the global scope at a separate *fixed* point on the page), so `roo` can see `foo` of its own accord.

Each function exists in one (and exactly one) place. All declarations do is make that place *visible* to the code that uses it. Code that doesn't use it, doesn't need to be able to see it. `main` can't see the nested call to `foo`, so any declaration at that point isn't relevant to it.

Comment: This was above and beyond what I needed to know. Thank you, I was most likely confusing the main point of the declaration and the definition, I really do need to get up and push myself into a refresher with regards to C. I was focusing too much on the exclusivity of the objects located within the scopes of the functions, I'm a bit new to C++, somewhat unrelated but I'm held up on the scope of objects created and things of the matter and may be mashing the two, badly I might add, into one entity. Thank you again for the explanation.